# Showing a topology is finer/coarser

Tags: general-topology

The following theorem is given:
"Let $(X, \tau_1)$ and $(X, \tau_2)$ be topological spaces. Then $\tau_1$ is coarser than $\tau_2$ if and only if for each $x \in X$ and every $U \in \tau_1$ with $x \in U$ there exists a $V \in \tau_2$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$."

I was wondering whether the theorem is still true if I only apply them for basis elements. Since every open set is unions of basis, if I can show that the theorem above is true for basis elements, then I can show one topology is finer/coarser than another correct?

Comment: Yes, the condition holds for open sets iff it holds for basic open sets.

Comment: In fact, the statement only has power when restricted for basis elements. On the topology level itself, you can have something much stronger; namely, for every $U \in \tau_1$, we have that $U \in \tau_2$ and so you can always take $V = U$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes we can restrict to bases:

If $(X,\tau_1)$ has a base $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $(X.\tau_2)$ has a base $\mathcal{B}_2$ then $\tau_1$ is coarser than $\tau_2$ iff

$$\forall x \in X: \forall U \in \mathcal{B}_1: (x \in U) \to (\exists V \in \mathcal{B}_2: x \in V \subseteq U)\tag{1}$$

That (1) holds if $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ is clear: the basic $U$ is open in $\tau_1$ and so also in $\tau_2$ so the last fact follows from $\mathcal{B}_2$ being a base for it.

And *if* $(1)$ holds, write  $U \in \tau_1$ as a union of basic sets $B' \in \mathcal{B}_1$ and then we write each such $B'$ as a union of elements from $\mathcal{B}_2$ using $(1)$ (for each $x$ in $B'$ take some $B_x \in \mathcal{B}_2$ with $x \in B_x \subseteq B'$ and union up those $B_x$) which
is thus $\tau_2$-open and so $\mathcal{B}_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ from which $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ follows directly.