# Confirmation a topology is coarser than the Euclidean metric

Tags: general-topology

I have read through this question that has been asked [Showing a topology is finer/coarser](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993749/showing-a-topology-is-finer-coarser)

I have a topological space $(X,T)$ which is a family of subsets of $\mathbb R$ including $\emptyset$, $\mathbb R$ itself and intervals of the form $(-\infty,a)$. Having used this question I've stated that this topology is coarser than the Euclidean metric as every open set of $T$ is also an open set in the Euclidean metric. I was wondering if someone could confirm this before I moved any further forward

Answer (score 1):

That proves correctly that $T$ is coarser than the Euclidian topology. Actually, it is *strictly* coarser since, for instance, $(-1,1)$ belongs to the Euclidian topology but not to $T$.